# FFMPEG. Using the concat command speeds up the video when merging two videos

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm just trying to join 2 videos using FFMPEG on PC. This is the splash screen and main video. But the second video changes speed (very fast). What should I add to the code?

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy video.mp4
```

I encoded the second video with the same codec as the first one, but it didn't help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the framerate for both videos the same?